# arcgis C#: restrict addin to mxd file only

Tags: arcmap, c#, add-in, arcgis-10.3

I have an addin toolbar (arcmap 10.3 in C#) for a certain type of analysis for our clients. We want to restrict the availability of the addin to a mxd file. We do not want other COM or Addins to be able to 'enable' it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the add-in enable or disable depending on the name of the mxd by putting a boolean test in the OnUpdate() sub. `If My.ArcMap.Application.Document.Title = Authorized.mxd Then Enabled = True`, or something like that.

You could also require a user to enter a password and have each add-in on your toolbar query the result in its OnUpdate() and then set `Enabled = True` or `Enabled = False` depending on if the password was correct or not. Of course that wouldn't be restricting the use to an mxd, but rather to authorized users, and would prevent savvy users from guessing that the mxd name is the key to using the tool.